# Framer motion animate when element is in-view (When you scroll to element)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

Is there any built-in way to make the animation start when the element is in-view (for example, when we scroll to the element)?

[Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animation/#mount-animations) has mount animations section which says:

> When a component mounts, it'll automatically animate to the values in animate if they're different from those defined in style or initial

So I couldn't really find a straight forward way to make the animation start when it comes into view.

However, I reached the only option I see for now is using [Animation Controls](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animation/#animation-controls) which means I'll have to implement a listener on the scroll manually and trigger the `control.start()`, any easier ways are much appreciated.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**`framer-motion` has built-in support for this use case since version 5.3.**

Here's a CodeSandbox demonstrating the pattern: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animate-in-view-5-3-94j13

Relevant code:

```
function FadeInWhenVisible({ children }) {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial="hidden"
      whileInView="visible"
      viewport={{ once: true }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
      variants={{
        visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
        hidden: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
<FadeInWhenVisible>
  <Box />
</FadeInWhenVisible>
```

**Previous versions:**

You can currently use the [imperative animation controls](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animation/#animation-controls) to achieve this effect. Intersection observers are useful to detect if an element is currently visible.

Here's a CodeSandbox demonstrating the pattern: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animate-in-view-gqcc8.

Relevant code:

```
function FadeInWhenVisible({ children }) {
  const controls = useAnimation();
  const [ref, inView] = useInView();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      controls.start("visible");
    }
  }, [controls, inView]);

  return (
    <motion.div
      ref={ref}
      animate={controls}
      initial="hidden"
      transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
      variants={{
        visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
        hidden: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this one

```
<motion.div
 initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
 whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
 viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.5 }}
 >
   hello
</motion.div>
```